# Need help to Check out source using Git

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I'm new to Git, and I have no idea what the heck should I do to check out the repository.

The source is at: `http://zmpp.git.sourceforge.net/git/zmpp`

How do I fetch all the files in the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download git from here: http://git-scm.com/downloads - for your operating system.

Open the *git-shell* - on most systems, easy way would be to double click on the icon labeled either of the following 'git-cmd', 'git-bash', 'git-terminal' or something similar.

*For example on windows:*
[image]

Once the shell has started, move to the folder where you want to checkout the source.

Say, you want to checkout the code at D:\SourceCode\ - given a [windows system](http://git-scm.com/download/win) - using `git-bash` - type the following:

```
cd /d/SourceCode
```

and then `clone` the repository - as follows.

```
git clone http://zmpp.git.sourceforge.net/git/zmpp
```

[image]

The above will create a folder `zmpp` which will contain the entire repository for the project in question.

Comment: it's giving this error:

`$ git clone http://zmpp.git.sourceforge.net/git/
Cloning into 'git'...
fatal: http://zmpp.git.sourceforge.net/git/info/refs not found: did you run git
update-server-info on the server?`

@xk0der

Comment: Hey! I just Googled the project online - you may want to try their git:// URL - `git clone git://zmpp.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/zmpp/zmpp` - That should work, If I got the project right.

Answer (score 2):

[git clone http://zmpp.git.sourceforge.net/git/zmpp](http://cworth.org/hgbook-git/tour/)

Also [this](http://gitref.org/creating/) will give further details.

Comment: and how can I set path to the local directory where the files will be stored? @vincentramdhanie

Comment: @DerpyDerp `clone` creates the directory wherever you run it and you can do whatever you want after that.

Comment: @DerpyDerp Don't forget to mark an answer and upvote anything you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and a helpful user at the Ubuntuforums pointed out that when using the git:// handler, you must open up port 9418 on your firewall.

So...

```
git clone git://projectname.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/project/subproject
```

would require this rule to be added in Linux (for instance, /etc/sysconfig/iptables on Fedora/RedHat variants):

```
-A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9418 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "GIT"
```